# Is it possible to have "Cancel" button with "Apply" button for Non reactive Property Pane in New SharePoint Framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

whether it is possible to have "Cancel" button with "Apply" button for Non reactive Property Pane in New SharePoint Framework. i Have followed link https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/staging/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/design-considerations-for-web-parts.md where we have Apply and cancel both buttons for Non Reactive Pane. I have used below function override to make Webpart Non reactive.

*protected get disableReactivePropertyChanges(): boolean {
    return true;
  }*

Apply button automatically appear in Property Pane but not cancel Button.am i missing some other property or configuration to bring the cancel Button in Property Pane.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have done the right thing, and while there is no cancel button, the X in the top corner of the property pane will do the same thing.  We went through a few designs, and people found the cancel to be problematic.  However, there is a bug (I've added it here https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/337 ) where when you hit the X and come back to the property pane, the values you edited (but didn't apply) still show up.  Those should have the original properties that are saved in the webpart, not the edited ones.

Comment: even I have realize this same issue. even without Apply, Edited Property remains intact when again we open the property Pane.Hope it will fix in future.